# javascript popup window loads parent url

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a web page where they want the person to sign up for something.  As a result, they have an alert window on the page, the person hits the "sign up" button, and the alert window loads with a form.

No big deal about that.  However, on the browser page underneath, and on the form on the second stage of signup, there are links to standard disclaimer pages.  They want these to be pop up windows when the user clicks on them.

When I was testing it out, in generic form (no user signed in - the page and disclaimers are declared "public" so you don't need to be logged in to see them), it worked fine.

However, if the user is logged in, when you hit the disclaimer links, it instead loads that same "signup" page - the parent page!

I'll post my coding, but what I'm looking for is twofold - is there an easy way to keep other content from loading in that popup?

If not, I'm guessing that it has something to do with that omnipresent signup popup/alert, and as this other content gets pulled in, there's coding that tells it to load any subsequent popups with that same page.  Is there some kind of language I should be looking for?  It's all very modular, with a lot of includes, to tracking things down can be tricky.  Less so if someone has some suggestions, I'd guess.

---

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">`

```
// Popup window code

var popupWindow = null;

function popitup(url2,winName,w,h,t,l,scroll){

settings =

'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+t+',left='+l+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
popupWindow = window.open(url2,winName,settings)
}

</script>`
```

`<p>&copy; <%=Year(now)%>&nbsp;<%=usr_Company%> All Rights Reserved.`
`<a style="color: #898787;" href="info_privacy1.asp" onclick="popitup(this.href,'disclose','700','780','100','200','yes');return false">Privacy Policy</a>`  `| <a style="color: #898787;" href="info_terms1.asp" onclick="popitup(this.href,'disclose','700','780','100','200','yes');return false">Terms of Service</a> <br /><br />`

```
    <%=brand_name%> legal disclaimer blah blah blah blah blah.<br /><br />
</p>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: Shonwing servercode does not help. Show the output in view source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the JS know that the user is signed in. Few ways to do this - AJAX, but more so simply on page load -IDK what you are using - php or whatever, but what it should do is this:

if user is signed in, print out a globav variable to javascript "userSignedIn = 1"

then when the user clicks a link, js checks if userSignedIn is set to 1, and if it is, it will not display the signup window, but continue to the next one, if userSignedin is not set (or is not 1), the signup form will be displayed...